# Python subproccess.call(unzip) not taking variable for exdir

Tags: django, subprocess, unzip

This is what I am doing:

```
pathToZip = '/it/is/right/here.zip'
pathToOut = '/I/would/like/that/right/here'
unzip = ('unzip', pathToZip, '-d', pathToOut)
p = subprocess.call(unzip)
```

Doesn't work, print p returns 2. However, this:

```
unzip = ('unzip', pathToZip, '-d', '/I/would/like/that/right/here')
```

works.

What simple thing in the help/manual am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code even though I normally use list instead of tuple for the argument.

The best now is testing on Python console, you should know the source of the problem right away.

Does the content of the zip file already present in the `exdir`? In that case it would ask if you want to replace / overwrite that content. You can use `-o` to always overwrite.

```
pathToZip = '/it/is/right/here.zip'
pathToOut = '/I/would/like/that/right/here'
unzip = ['unzip', '-o', pathToZip, '-d', pathToOut]
p = subprocess.call(unzip)
```